# How to identify require expressions that are not needed?

Tags: ruby

How to tell if we have unused require expressions?

For example:

```rb
require 'colorize'
require_relative './helpers'

puts 'Hello, world!'
```

This is a very simple example but there can be larger/complex cases when after some refactoring we forget to remove the requires, is there an easy way to identify those unused requires? Rubocop doesn't seem to have a rule for that.

Comment: Well, those packages *aren’t* required, right?  So it’s conveying false information, and potentially causing you to install dependencies that aren’t needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, [`Kernel#require`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require), [`Kernel#require_relative`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative), and [`Kernel#load`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-load) simply execute the file being `require`d. In other words, the expressions (by the way, they are not statements, they are expressions, everything in Ruby is an expression, there are no statements) are *not* unused.

They execute the side-effects in those files. In other words: they are *not* NO-OPs. Removing them or not removing them might actually change the behavior of your program!

You need to carefully analyze the contents of `colorize.rb` and `helpers.rb` to see whether their side-effects might influence your program.